# gdalwarp antimeridian issue

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, antimeridian

I realise there are similar questions but I could not find the exact same.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
gdalwarp  -t_srs '+proj=stere +lat_0=YY +lon_0=XX +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=1737400 +b=1737400 +units=m +no_defs' 1.tif 2.tif
```

Where YY in the problem case is 25 and XX -178 (Yes I realise now that `+a=1737400 +b=1737400` could just be `+R=1737400`. It makes no difference)

This seems to work fine everywhere except where 1.tif contains the antimeridian.

I have found suggestions about `+over` and `+lon_wrap=180` and `--config CENTER_LONG 180` on other threads that I tried. I also tried different projections just to see if that was the issue, among other things.

Finally, I tried simply running `gdalwarp 1.tif 2.tif`.

In all cases the result was the same, namely a tif with no valid data.

```
ERROR 1: 2.tif, band 1: Failed to compute statistics, no valid pixels found in sampling.
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=0
```

Gdalinfo for 1.tif gives (among other things):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
...
Size is 12288, 12288
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["SIMPLE_CYLINDRICAL MOON",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_MOON",
        DATUM["D_MOON",
            ELLIPSOID["MOON",1737400,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Equidistant Cylindrical",
        METHOD["Equidistant Cylindrical",
            ID["EPSG",1028]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
PROJ.4 string is:
'+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs'
Origin = (5458199.374783761799335,2092314.880853968206793)
Pixel Size = (7.403161724669900,-7.403161724669900)
...
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 5458199.375, 2092314.881) (179d59'59.56"E, 69d 0' 0.44"N)
Lower Left  ( 5458199.375, 2001344.830) (179d59'59.56"E, 66d 0' 0.44"N)
Upper Right ( 5549169.426, 2092314.881) (177d 0' 0.44"W, 69d 0' 0.44"N)
Lower Right ( 5549169.426, 2001344.830) (177d 0' 0.44"W, 66d 0' 0.44"N)
Center      ( 5503684.400, 2046829.855) (178d30' 0.44"W, 67d30' 0.44"N)
Band 1 Block=12288x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=205.000, Mean=29.882, StdDev=17.628
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=205
    STATISTICS_MEAN=29.882287511606
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=17.628075699679
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=40.5
```

My conclusion is that gdalwarp cannot even read the file correctly. Can you help?

Comment: what does `gdal_info` say about your input tiff

Comment: This (among other things):
```
Band 1 Block=12288x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=1.000 Max=140.000
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=140.000, Mean=25.562, StdDev=16.643
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=140
    STATISTICS_MEAN=25.561719810576
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=16.642602338338
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=61.81

```

Comment: Also: '+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs'

Comment: please [edit] your question with the new information