# How to solve antimeridian split using GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp, antimeridian

I'm fairly new to GIS and GDAL. But I need to solve the problem with anti-meridian. I have satellite images from Meteor-M2 that can span over -180 / 180 longitude.

I created .vrt file with correct GCP and running gdalwarp using the command below:

```
gdalwarp -tps -overwrite -t_srs epsg:3857 -of GTIFF 2022_12_20_06_26_30.vrt 2022_12_20_06_26_30.tiff
```

GCPs are in the EPSG:4326. I'm trying to project it to the mercator - epsg:3857. But every time I do it QGIS is showing messed up thing:

[image: antimeridian gdalwarp]

There was suggestion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443895/splitting-polygons-crossing-the-antimeridian) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423987/gdalwarp-antimeridian-issue). But they either do not work or require creating 2 different images.

I have several questions:

1. Is it possible to create (find?) such projection based on longlat that won't suffer from anti-meridian issue?
2. Why QGIS and GDAL can't handle such common thing? Is it something fundamentally geo-specific or tools simply doesn't support that?

Part of .vrt file:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="1568" rasterYSize="4176">
<GCPList Projection="EPSG:4326">
<GCP Id="0" Pixel="1568.5" Line="0.5" X="149.52915755044418" Y="-45.837704600923644" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="1" Pixel="1504.5" Line="0.5" X="154.43424433649258" Y="-45.93729380958608" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="2" Pixel="1440.5" Line="0.5" X="157.58073641820582" Y="-45.889746060989616" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="3" Pixel="1376.5" Line="0.5" X="159.891809252493" Y="-45.79921318528995" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="4" Pixel="1312.5" Line="0.5" X="161.7173576867272" Y="-45.694190106015654" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="5" Pixel="1248.5" Line="0.5" X="163.23041011080574" Y="-45.584557546614604" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="6" Pixel="1184.5" Line="0.5" X="164.5297632858649" Y="-45.47393921636255" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="7" Pixel="1120.5" Line="0.5" X="165.6774237615475" Y="-45.36347704459805" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="8" Pixel="1056.5" Line="0.5" X="166.7151442282367" Y="-45.253213065130666" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="9" Pixel="992.5" Line="0.5" X="167.67271533465774" Y="-45.14264923806328" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="10" Pixel="928.5" Line="0.5" X="168.57253406297082" Y="-45.03098214978519" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="11" Pixel="864.5" Line="0.5" X="169.43232459562935" Y="-44.91719326883545" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="12" Pixel="800.5" Line="0.5" X="170.26688277172218" Y="-44.80006601833679" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="13" Pixel="736.5" Line="0.5" X="171.0892891524139" Y="-44.678157669363706" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="14" Pixel="672.5" Line="0.5" X="171.9118417215573" Y="-44.549734060640155" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="15" Pixel="608.5" Line="0.5" X="172.74686989641376" Y="-44.41266308839782" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="16" Pixel="544.5" Line="0.5" X="173.60755715225582" Y="-44.2642518790569" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="17" Pixel="480.5" Line="0.5" X="174.50890318780168" Y="-44.100997541514076" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="18" Pixel="416.5" Line="0.5" X="175.46900047950982" Y="-43.91819563457606" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="19" Pixel="352.5" Line="0.5" X="176.51090804376494" Y="-43.70930065986558" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="20" Pixel="288.5" Line="0.5" X="177.66564308695098" Y="-43.46482793272547" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="21" Pixel="224.5" Line="0.5" X="178.9773538004857" Y="-43.17034497075211" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="22" Pixel="160.5" Line="0.5" X="-179.48690939379856" Y="-42.80248427658728" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="23" Pixel="96.5" Line="0.5" X="-177.61654129184285" Y="-42.3200985765115" Z="0.0" />
<GCP Id="24" Pixel="1.5" Line="0.5" X="-173.72678903385165" Y="-41.191670087805825" Z="0.0" />
```

Comment: I can't imagine how projecting to Web Mercator could help in this situation. You need to split the image.

Comment: possibly try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438910/gdalwarp-antimeridian-problem-on-tif-with-gcps